# OSM Hebrew caption are left to right instead of right to left in QGIS

Tags: openstreetmap, hebrew

Whew I am usieng [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) maps in QGIS the Hebrew caption are in the right order, right to left [image]
However, when I am downloading the streets with "OSMDownloader InaSAFE" plugin the words are left to right. I am using UTF-8 encoding and the caption in the Attribute Table are in the right order.[image]

How can I solved this and display this Hebrew caption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the display in the Attribute Table is correct it is clear that the encoding is fine and the problum is with the label display.
After some digging, this problem appear only when I am using the "curved" placement. When I am using "Horizontal" or "Parallel" placement the caption are right to left, as they should be. [image]